# Delete a string between 2 delimiters on possibly different lines

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

Background: I have a config file that stores values in variations of this format:

(below is an example using fictitious data)

```
'names': { "john", "jeff", "stewie", "amy", "emily" }
```

Some formatting details:

- there is never a space between 'names' and :
- there may-or-may-not be a space between "{" and "john"
- there is always a space between members of the list ("john" always
  has a ", " before "jeff")
- there may-or-may-not be a space between "emily" and "}"
- the elements in this list may be delineated by line instead of by
  space.  For example, this is also acceptable:

  ```
  'names': { "john",
             "jeff",
             "stewie",
             "amy",
             "emily"
           }
  ```

So is this:

```
    'names': { "john", "jeff", "stewie",
               "amy", "emily" }
```

The functionality I'm trying to create: I'd like to delete "amy" from the list named 'names'.

I've been trying to create this behavior using sed, but I'm open to using bash, awk, cut or some combination of these.

If the elements of the list were on a single line, this would be easy:

```
/bin/sed -i "/names/ s/ ${element}//" $f
```

(where `$element` contains `"amy"` and `$f` contains the file I'm editing

But the multi-line possibility throws me.

Thoughts?

Comment: The other examples of the 'names' list were suppose to show each element on a separate line, or some elements on line 1, the others on line2.  Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Comment: something about the S.O. auto-formatter doesn't like your first example, which has each element on a line. But if people solve the 2nd one, you'll be in good shape. Good luck!

Comment: `sed` is not a good tool when records can span lines. `awk` would be better.

Comment: Can names contains `,` like: `'names': { "john", "jeff,more", "stewie", "amy", "emily" }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider this input file that contains all three cases:

```
$ cat file
'names': { "john", "jeff", "stewie", "amy", "emily" }
'names': { "john",
           "jeff",
           "stewie",
           "amy",
           "emily"
         }
'names': { "john", "jeff", "stewie",
               "amy", "emily" }
```

Now, let's apply this `sed` command to remove `amy`:

```
$ sed '/names/{:a;/}/!{N;b a}; s/"amy",[[:space:]]*//}' file
'names': { "john", "jeff", "stewie", "emily" }
'names': { "john",
           "jeff",
           "stewie",
           "emily"
         }
'names': { "john", "jeff", "stewie",
               "emily" }
```

#### How it works

- `/names/`

  Any time a line contains `names`, we begin our commands.  Other lines are passed through unchanged.
- `:a; /}/! {N;b a}`

  Once we have our line containing `names`, we read in additional lines until we get one that contains the closing brace.  This gets the complete `names` assignment in at once even if it is spread over multiple lines.

  In more detail, `:a` is a label.  `/}/!` is a condition.  If the line does not contain `}`, then the statements `N; b a` are executed.  `N` reads in the next line and adds it to the pattern space.  `b a` jumps (branches) back to the label `a`.  Thus, this continues until the complete assignment, from `names` to `}`, is in the pattern space.
- `s/"amy",[[:space:]]*//}`

  With the complete `names` assignment in sed's pattern space, we look for `"amy",` and any whitespaces which follow and we remove them.

#### Removing amy even when she is last in the list

The above solution assumes that a comma follows the name `amy`.  Suppose, however, that `amy` is could be the last name in the list, as in the following file:

```
$ cat file
'names': { "john", "jeff", "stewie", "emily", "amy" }
'names': { "john",
           "jeff",
           "stewie",
           "emily",
           "amy"
         }
'names': { "john", "jeff", "stewie",
               "emily", "amy"}
```

To handle this situation, we need add one substitute command:

```
$ sed '/names/{:a;/}/!{N;b a}; s/"amy",[[:space:]]*//; s/,[[:space:]]*"amy"//}' file
'names': { "john", "jeff", "stewie", "emily" }
'names': { "john",
           "jeff",
           "stewie",
           "emily"
         }
'names': { "john", "jeff", "stewie",
               "emily"}
```

Comment: This is an impressive sed expression!  Well done :)  The only issue I see with it is that it will fail on the tail entry; in the above example an attempt to delete "emily" will fail because it doesn't have a trailing comma.  Fixing that is potentially easy (add a "*" after the ","), but that will result in the new trailing entry having a trailing comma).   Thoughts?

Comment: @carab1n3r To handle that case, I would add a second substitute command.  See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

using sed as follows:

```
sed  -r ':loop;$!{N;b loop};s/(.names.: ?\{[^}]*)"amy",? *([^}]*\})/\1\2/g' my-file
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use bash string handling routines, copied directly from:

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

```
stringZ=abcABC123ABCabc
echo ${stringZ/abc/xyz}
```

result = bcABC123ABCxyz

In your case

```
export stringZ="\'names\': \{ \"john\", \"jeff\", \"stewie\", \"amy\", \"emily\" }"

echo ${stringZ/\"amy\",/}
```

returns 'names': { "john", "jeff", "stewie", "emily" }